# Change headers for a specific file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox-os

I have a `manifest.webapp` file in my app's `public` folder.

I can access it in normally, but the request came as `text/plain`, and I need it to be `application/x-web-app-manifest+json`.

I tried to put the following in my `environment`:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/x-web-app-manifest+json", :webapp
```

But it didn't work as expected. Probably I'm missing something.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

### [EDIT]

Only for local tests, in remote I just changed the nginx `mime.types` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your mime files of your web server (Nginx, Lighttpd or Apache).

I use this link for helping me : http://9elements.com/io/index.php/make-ogg-video-work-with-rails/

Comment: This already is cited in my answer... I asking how to do this in rails test environment. Thanks